# How to correctly call servlet with window.open?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have servlet with url pattern /servlet. I'm calling it by

```
function func(id){window.open ("../servlet?fileId="+id, "hiddenFrame");}
```

via href in jsp which doesn't work. However accessing it via URL /servlet?fileId=2 works. I think it's a servlet mapping issue. Kindly help.

**Update: I have added the code below**

index.jsp has only the statement:

```
<%request.getRequestDispatcher("newjsp.jsp").forward(request,response);%>
```

newjsp.jsp has the code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function func (id)
{
    window.open ("/servlet?fileId="+id, "hiddenFrame");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   <% 
       out.println("<a href='javascript:func(2)'>Link</a>");
   %>
</body>
<iframe src="about:blank" name="hiddenFrame" width=0 height=0 frameborder=0>
</iframe>
</html>
```

servlet.java has code:

```
package newpackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "servlet", urlPatterns = {"/servlet"})
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet servlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: First of all the url you have used in the window.open method above contains two dots.Check on that first . Secondly please take pains to provide the exact error trace.

Comment: @professionallyme86 I've removed dots but still doesn't work. I'm not getting any error. The click returns nothing but a hover on link displays  'javascript:func(2)'

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: @professionallyme86 please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a funny issue. You have used "/servlet" as the URL in your window.open() method. This bypasses the application root folder and forms the URL as http://localhost/servet whereas actual URL should be something like http://localhost//servlet .

Any ways the solution in your case would be to just remove that "/" from the URL. Hence use :

```
window.open ("servlet?fileId="+id, "hiddenFrame")
```